# Why is jQuery on-click event handler not working properly for dynamic loaded DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I load my JavaScript file in the  at my home page, then I navigate to the page where I need a onclick function. The onclick is attached to content that has been loaded dynamically over time via AJAX calls. The elements I try to reach are constructed like:

```
<a href="#" id="query_2" class="list-group-item query">Alle huurdergegevens</a>
```

And in my JavaScript file I wrote this:

```
$(".query").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.replace(/\D/g,'');
    console.log(id);
    exeSQL(id);
});
```

When I click the element, literally nothing happens.. Nothing logged in the console, no errors aswell.. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong tbh..

Comment: I think you having this issue because you have not put your onclick script inside document.ready function.

Comment: The problem is that since you load the content dynamically, your jquery code doesn't add the click events to the loaded elements. You'd need to attach the click listeners after you're done with loading the content, or then you can use the answer by Sagar Arora. :)

Answer (score 10):

when you load any element in DOM after DOM is created then you have to handle click event like this with using `on`

```
$(document).on("click",".query",function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.replace(/\D/g,'');
    console.log(id);
    exeSQL(id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this did it! Could you eloberate on how this works... ?

Comment: @LaurensMäkel because your content is loaded dynamically so in  that case we have to use $(document) instead of direct selector element.

Comment: @LaurensMäkel, check the documentation for [jQuery.on() here](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). `When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as delegated.` --> `Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this syntax for events on dynamic content

```
$(document).on('click','.query',function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.replace(/\D/g,'');
    console.log(id);
    exeSQL(id);
});
```

See an example :

```js
$(document).on('click', '#myButton', function(){
  alert('ok')
})
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="submit" id="myButton"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">         </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that stumbles across this like I did, the following is how I ended up here and also why the top answer solves the problem:

- I was using `body` for my event handlers: `$('body').on('contextmenu', '#myctl', function(e) {`
- My event handlers were bound to *dynamic* and *static* elements
- The event handlers were working when in my main page
- They stopped working when I moved them to an *external* JS file

The solution in the top answer solved my problem because it used `$(document)` to bind the event handlers instead of `$('body')`.

**Why?**

The reason that moving to `$(document)` solves the issue is that `$('body')` doesn't actually exist in the external JS file.  By using `$(document)`, JQuery is able to attach the event handler to something that actually exists and the event handlers start working again.

**Summary**

If using event handlers (for statis or dynamic elements) in external JS files, use `$(document).on(...)` instead of `$('body').on(...)`.