# Click event for button created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my AJAX success function, I've written:

```
rt = JSON.parse(responseText);
for (i = 0; i < rt.length; i++) {
  $("#inv").append("<tr><td>" + rt[i][0] +
    "</td><td><input type='submit' value='Sync' " +
    "class='syncnow' id='sync"+rt[i][6]+"' /></td></tr>");
}
```

I've tried jQuery code:

```
$(".syncnow").on("click", function() {
  alert("Hi");
});
```

Tried `.click()`, `$(".tdclass").on("click", ".syncnow", function() {})` etc., but to no avail.  Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Actually this helps : $("body").on("click",".syncnow", function() {} )

Comment: Read Jquery https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler

Comment: Are you getting any error's in the browser console ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$("body").on("click",".syncnow", function() {} )
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: I just posted the answer copying from someone who previously commented on the question and then removed the comment. Thats why I didnt post the explanation

Answer (score 2):

You can't add an event to a not yet created element. You need to add it to a higher place and catch it when it is bubbling up.
Try this:

```js
$("body").on("click", ".syncnow", function() {
  console.log('clicked');
} )

$("#inv").append("<input type='submit' value='Sync' class='syncnow' id='sync' />");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inv">
</div>
```

Comment: This also does not work

Comment: works great for me, `console log` get's run when I click the button

Answer (score 1):

You can attach event to element when created using `jQuery()`

```
$.each(rt, function(i, value) {
  $("<tr>", {
    appendTo: "#inv",
    html: $("<td>", {
            html: value[0],
            append: $("<input>", {
                      type: "submit",
                      value: "Sync",
                      "class": "syncnow",
                      id: value[6],
                      on: {
                            click: function(event) {
                                     console.log("clicked");
                                   }
                          }
                    })
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```js
$(document).on("click", ".syncnow", function() {
  alert('clicked');
} )

$("#inv").append("<input type='submit' value='Sync' class='syncnow' id='sync' />");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a jquery function, to append `syncbuttons` to an `invElement`

```
$.fn.appendSyncElements = function(responseText, onComplete) {

    var invElement = $(this);
    var rt = JSON.parse(responseText);

    var base_sync_attrs = [];
    base_sync_attrs.push("type=\"submit\"");
    base_sync_attrs.push("value=\"Sync\"");
    base_sync_attrs.push("class=\"syncnow\"");
    var base_sync_attrs_str = base_sync_attrs.join(' ');

    for(var i = 0; i < rt.length; i++) {

        var crt = rt[i];
        var crt_sync_label = crt[0];
        var crt_sync_attrs = crt[6];

        var sync_attrs = [];
        sync_attrs.push(base_sync_attrs_str);
        sync_attrs.push("id=\"sync_" + String(i) + "\"");
        sync_attrs.push("data-sync_index=\"" + String(i) + "\"");
        sync_attrs.push(crt_sync_attrs);
        var sync_attrs_str = sync_attrs.join(' ');

        var syncElement = $('<input ' + sync_attrs_str + ' />');

        syncElement.click(function(e) {
            var syncBtn = $(this);
            console.log("the syncBtn was clicked at index " + String(syncBtn.data('sync_index'));
            var syncEvent = {
                'event' : e,
                'button' : syncBtn,
                'fullresponse': crt,
            };
            if(typeof(onComplete) === 'function') {
                onComplete(syncEvent)
            };
        });

        var tableRowElement = $('<tr><td class="synclabel" ></td><td class="syncinput" ></td></tr>');
        tableRowElement.find("td.synclabel").html(crt_sync_label);
        tableRowElement.find("td.syncinput").append(syncElement);

        invElement.append(tableRowElement);

    };


};
```

Usage

```
$("#inv").appendSyncElements(responseText);
```

Or

```
$("#inv").appendSyncElements(responseText, function(syncResult) {
    console.log("This is a custom Complete Method");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use document on click event:

```
$(document).on("click",".syncnow",function() {
   alert("Working");
});
```

Also you can check my answer here:

[Why is jQuery on-click event handler not working properly for dynamic loaded DOM elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42644949/why-is-jquery-on-click-event-handler-not-working-properly-for-dynamic-loaded-dom/42645003#42645003)

Thanks